# Exporting color information and font sizes from Illustrator to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation

I am looking for some tool that would allow me to **export the all the artboards** from Illustrator to PDF (can also be any common image file) that would automatically create:

- labels with **colors** used (preferably RGB)
- labels with **font sizes**, pointed to a given label when the font has been used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a script. You could have it analyze each object for its `fillColor` and then create a label on a new layer that's either on top of the object or offset. If the object is a text frame, then you can have it look for various `characterAttributes` such as font size, and then create a label for that as well. Illustrator allows you to script PDF exports as well; see `PDFSaveOptions` in the [scripting reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html).